# EF: Adding new item in a collection and notifying all other collections that new item is added

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Lest say that we have several pages that retrieve items from the same EntitySet. If I add a new entity on one page, I need to add it to both EntitySet collection and myCollection:

```
Context.EntitySet.Add(item);
myCollection.Add(item);
```

What is the best way to notify other pages that new item is added (or deleted)? Editing an entity is no problem, since all pages get change notification without any problem.

Comment: Are you able to use `Context.EntitySet` instead of different instances of `myCollection`? Why are you creating a parallel collection to store entities in?

Comment: You got me suprises by the idea to bind directly to EntitySet, in all the material I have read/watched this was never a suggested option. Anyway, I could also do what you suggest with IEnumerable<T>, I just need to reference the same instance from each VM. The problem: how will I get the fresh data from data store, if I am always querying the same collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to different instances of `IEnumerable<T> myCollection`, the recommended approach is to bind directly to `Context.EntitySet<T>`. `EntitySet<T>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces. When you bind to the same instance of `EntitySet<T>`, each page may be notified of changes by responding to the `EntitySet<T>.CollectionChanged` event. For example:

```
// Page 1
_myCollection = Context.EntitySet<MyItem>();
_myCollection.CollectionChanged += MyItemsChanged;

...

// Page 2
_myCollection = Context.EntitySet<MyItem>();
_myCollection.CollectionChanged += MyItemsChanged;
```

When any page adds or removes from the collection, all pages are notified.

In regards to your comment, `IEnumerable<T>` does not implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface and does not publish any change notifications. The best results come from using the `EntitySet<T>` directly.

Comment: I just gave an example of IEnumerable<T>, since it can be used to construct any other collection type (ex ObservableCollection<T>). Still, your method is not clear to me. If I always bind to the same source (in your case EntitySet<T>, this means that data is retrieved only once from the database. When and how will I query for the fresh data, which are modififed by other user on the network?